# Tracking object changes

Tags: javascript

Like to get some feedback/thoughts about the following challenge.

I have been working on a two way binding library reaching completion and left with an enhancement and looking for the best approach moving forward.

I am tracking the properties of an object (e.g. state) with basic getters/setters. On changes routines are executed to update the DOM. Extremely simplified example:

```
var state = {propertyA:1,propertyB:2,propertyC:3}
state.forEach((prop) => {
    Object.defineProperty(state, prop, {
        set: function (newValue) {
            value = newValue;
            // routines to update the DOM based on the changed state
        },
        get: function () {
            return value;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
}
```

However runtime this state object might end up receiving new properties. I seek to remove the dependency of having to manually reinitialize all properties again.

So I need to track the state object and add the necessary setters/getters for the appended properties. I tried the following, but I am not allowed to touch the state object despite having set configurable to true.

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'state', {
    set: function (newValue) {
        value = newValue;
        // routine to apply setters/getters for the new properties
    },
    get: function () {
        return value;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

I really would like to avoid super nasty stuff like setInterval to check object changes. Any advice on how to handle this situation?

Comment: It's a difficult problem in general. What about arrays? What about primitives? The big boys like Angular, React and Vue don't depend on events to trigger when changes happen; rather, they choose to use some diffing algorithm (in Angular, on the input data; in React and Vue, on the resulting DOM).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Proxy`object to do this simply.

For the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

> The Proxy object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental
>   operations (e.g. property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function
>   invocation, etc).

```js
let state = {
  propertyA: 1,
  propertyB: 2,
  propertyC: 3
}

function wrapObject(state) {
  const handler = {
    get: function(obj, prop) {
      console.log("get invoked for prop:: ", prop);
      return prop;
    },
    set: function(obj, prop, value) {
      console.log("set invoked for prop:: ", prop, " and value:: ", value);
      document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = `<div> prop: ${prop} value: ${value} </div>`;
      //Other code
    }
  };
  return new Proxy(state, handler);
}

state = wrapObject(state);
state.propertyA;
state.propertyD = 4;
//Update state by adding new property after 3 secs
setTimeout(() => {
  state.propertyE = 5;
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: And plenty support today, great suggestion!